# How can I manually load several child Lists so they aren't eager loaded or lazy loaded?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes mapped in Entity Framework Core

```
public class Parent
{
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public int ChildId { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Grandchild> Grandchildren { get; set; }
}

public class Grandchild 
{
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public int ChildId { get; set; }
   public int GrandchildId { get; set; }
   public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

When I get an instance of `Parent` from the database, I want to eager load the `Children` list, but I want to manually load each child's `Grandchildren` list by first loading a complete list of grandchildren in a single query, and then assigning the appropriate elements to each `Child` element.  The reason I want to do this because eager loading of grandchildren produces a poorly performing query, and lazy loading each child element one-by-one also performs poorly.

My problem is that I don't know how to get Entity Framework's change tracker to consider the manually loaded lists to be unchanged, and also to consider the list as loaded so that it doesn't try to lazy load that list later.

```
public Parent LoadParent(int id)
{
   // .Include Children but not Grandchildren
   var parent = context.Parents.Where(p => p.ParentId == id)
      .Include(n => n.Children)
      .FirstOrDefault();

   Dictionary<int, List<Grandchild>> grandchildrenDictionary = context.Grandchildren
      .Where(p => p.ParentId == id)
      .GroupBy(k => k.ChildId)
      .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList())

   foreach (var child in parent.Children)
   {
      // This is where I'm not sure what to do.  How do I assign the Grandchildren
      // elements without making Entity Framework think that child.Grandchildren is
      // changed, and also without Entity Framework thinking that 
      // it still needs to lazy load Grandchildren
      child.Grandchildren = new();
      if (grandchildrenDictionary.TryGetValue(child.ChildId, out List<Grandchild> elements))
      {
         child.Grandchildren.AddRange(elements);
      }
   }

   return parent;
}
```

Comment: Do you need the parents to be tracked? If not, you could probably use .AsNoTracking().
Otherwise, you can manually mark the elements as unmodified with context.Entry(xxx).State = EntityState.Unchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With EF Core it can handle this scenario without producing the poorly performing Cartesian Product when eager loading via the `'AsSplitQuery()` option:

```
var parents = _context.Parents
    .Include(x => X.Children)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.GrandChildren)
    .Where(x => /* Insert Criteria */)
    .AsSplitQuery();
```

EF Core will then generate the appropriate queries to load the entities up and stitch the resulting entities together. If EF doesn't need to track these entities then you can add `.AsNoTracking()` to speed it up a tad.

However, when it comes to loading summary results it is rare to actually need entire entity graphs for every result. Rather, we can project a summary view model with just the details about the entity and its relations to flatten down and reduce the query and data coming back. For instance if we want logic that renders a state based on whether a Parent has a particular Grandchild or a count of Grandchildren, that can be projected through a `.Select()` rather than reading all Children and Grandchildren for results. EF builds a more complex query which should still leverage indexes, but the Cartesian Product is avoided with fewer rows and columns coming across and entities being composed. Eager loading entire graphs should be reserved for when you need a complete picture of a single object's graph rather than large result sets.

Alternatively you can fetch the grandchildren into the DbContext tracking cache first, then load your parents & Children:

```
 _context.Parents
    .Where(x => /* Insert Criteria */)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children.SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren))
    .ToList(); 
var parents = _context.Parents
    .Include(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => /* Insert Same Criteria */)
    .ToList();
```

EF will first load all Grandchild entities into the tracking cache. The second query only eager loads the Children, where EF will automatically populate the associated Grandchildren that it is tracking without producing the extra large Cartesian query. (One is still created for Parent+Children) That is more a trick for EF6, where with Core it is far better to use `AsSplitQuery()`. (Better yet is projection:)